# How does the volume of questions and answers on this site compare to physicsforums.com?

Tags: discussion

While I am a huge fan of stackexchange for some types of questions (ie: computer programming, Mathematica, latex), I still go to physicsforums.com for physics questions.

How does the volume of questions and answers on this physics stackexchange site compare to that of physicsforums.com?  Is this site attracting enough of a following that people are "defecting" from physicsforums?

Comment: By the way, any particular reason you prefer PF to here? If it's just a personal feeling, it's no problem, but if there's something we do that is driving people away from this site to PF, I'd love to know what it is.

Comment: Habit and a history of good answers there.

Comment: I love physics forums. They don't have strict homework policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rough estimate, it seems like Physics Forums gets about 500 threads per day, although not all of those are physics questions. On this site we get around 20 questions a day, or perhaps a few more. So I'd say PF has roughly 20 times the meaningful traffic that we do. However, it's worth keeping in mind that most of the questions there are simplistic homework questions of the sort that we generally discourage here. If you wonder about the figure of how many questions are asked at PF that we would like to have asked here, I'm sure it's significantly less than 20 times this site's activity.

I don't know whether people are "defecting" from PF to come here, but there's really no reason they need to - nothing stops someone from contributing to more than one Q&A site.